# How can I set expire headers on my web page?

Tags: html, css, caching

I asked a question about improving CSS load times and one answer suggested setting expire headers on my web page. Can someone explain how I can do this. I've never heard about it before.

Comment: You need a server-side technology (like PHP) to set a header expiry. What are you using? Try Firebug in Firefox, too, you can inspect the headers the browsers sees.

Comment: Using PHP for this? Certainly not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an apache trick you can do by creating a file called '.htaccess' and placing it in the root of your domain via FTP.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(css)$">
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 hours"
</FilesMatch>
```

Paste that in your .htaccess file and it will set the header f r css files. Add more filetypes, (css|js)

or cache-control for non-apache users:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

In fact, use all of the tricks your server supports in this article, your site will be noticeably faster:

http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/

Comment: your answer assumes he's using apache which was not actually specified.

Comment: I'm not using apache :-(  I'm using the IE server that comes with Azure.

Comment: He wants to set expires headers. The alternative would be cache-control, but he didn't say cache-control. I assume his server supports apache since he wants to set expires headers.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry about saying the wrong thing. I didn't know it was cache-control.

Comment: Cache-control is a non-apache alternative to expires. They do essentially the same thing, set cache time. No problem about the expires thing, it's easy to get confused.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html#LeverageBrowserCaching

Answer (score -2):

This goes in your root .htaccess file but if you have access to httpd.conf that is better

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2010 20:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

For the specified file format will be cached and will prevent users to make extra HTTP requests

Comment: Why would one want to use an absolute date there? And in your case even one in the past which effectively **disables** caching.

Comment: I am not sure i can give the relative date, for my website I am giving in the above format.